# After upgrade MacOS terminal showing: zsh: command not found: flutter

Tags: flutter, macos, zsh

Recently I updated Mac OS to latest Catalina. Now when entering a flutter command like the following,

```
flutter --version
```

my terminal (which is using zsh) shows me following error:

```
zsh: command not found: flutter
```

How do I reinstate the path to allow `flutter` commands from any directory?

Comment: first answer ok, but for who does not like vim here is other way
for Ubuntu users:
1. open terminal ``` ctrl + alt + t ```
2. `` nano $HOME/.zshrc ```
3. at the end of the file add the following line ( please replace [flutter_dir] with your director
``` export PATH=$PATH:[flutter_dir]/flutter/bin ```
4. exit -> save ``` ctrl + x ```
5. source ~/.zshrc

Comment: This question is clearly relevant to software tools primarily used by programmers.  The fact that as of today it has 90 upvotes and that the most-upvoted answer has 305 upvotes shows how many people have found this question useful.

Comment: In my case, my problem was the relative path to the flutter folder. I changed it to the absolute path and it was all fine.

Comment: This question shouldn't have been closed.

Comment: This question shouldn't have been closed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed [URL](https://superuser.com/questions/886132/where-is-the-zshrc-file-on-mac) to resolve my issue.

I simply created a .zshrc file which was not exist then added my PATH variables copied from existing .bashrc.

Comment: please provide the url's content, as URL's may expire

Answer (score 411):

You need to update the environment path.

1. Open terminal.
2. `vim $HOME/.zshrc`
3. Press "I" key for going to insert mode.
4. add the following line in the opened file:

   `export PATH="$PATH:/YOUR_FLUTTER_DIR/flutter/bin"`
5. Press "Esc" then write `:wq!` in terminal and press enter to exit vim.
6. Reopen the terminal and check "flutter doctor"

**If this solution did not work, remove the double quote from path or use the full path explicitly instead of `~`.**

Comment: Thanks. I actually used the format of PATH in my system "export PATH=/FLUTTER_DIR/flutter/bin:$PATH" and it works. the $PATH proceeds after the flutter dir

Comment: is the "I" key the pipe? Or capital "I" as in Indigo or lower case "l" as in lima?

Comment: I need to remove double quote from path to get it work..

Comment: This worked wonders! Thanks!  
I already had an anaconda block added automatically by the installation, I wrote export PATH=$PATH:~/development/flutter/bin above it and now both work fine.

Comment: Removing double quotes was what was needed for me. Thanks!

Comment: This ```export PATH="$HOME/.flutter/bin:$PATH"``` worked for me. On macOS Big Sur 11.2.3(Apple M1).

Comment: I can't understand, you solution works for me but `flutter` extends only in `$HOME` directory. If I call `flutter` in sub directory, for example `$HOME/Downloads`, it still says `flutter not found`. What should I do?

Comment: didn't work for me with or without double quotes

Comment: Also Exit terminal and again open it. to run flutter doctor in working state.

Comment: don't forget to type `source .zshrc` after editing .zshrc

Comment: @GiordanPretelin thanks you saved my time.  export PATH=$PATH:~/flutter/bin

Comment: If this solution did not work,
write it: 
`export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/development/flutter/bin"`

Comment: export PATH=$PATH:/YOUR_FLUTTER_DIR/flutter/bin works for me. Without the double quote. 

Also, I had the same line twice and I faced the same error. Make sure that you have only one line.

Comment: I is capital i, @Crystal

Comment: Removing double quotes was what was needed for me. Thanks

Comment: I was searching how to do this, thank you man. If I had 2 accounts I would push 2 upvotes for you.

Comment: for me adding this export line to .zshenv file(not .zshrc) helped

Answer (score 97):

**Working on macOS Catalina 10.15.5 (19F101).**
I have used **.zprofile** instead of **.zhrc**

1. Provide Full Disk Access to Terminal by
   Setting -> Security & Privacy -> Full Disk Access. Add Terminal
2. If the current terminal uses bash, change to zshell using the below command

   `chsh -s /bin/zsh`
3. In the root directory i.e something like /Users/^YourAccount^ execute the below

   `touch .zprofile`

   `vim .zprofile`
4. Press I to enter insert mode. Type the below

   `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/^YourAccount^/^YourPath^/flutter/bin`
5. Save and quit by pressing Esc, then :wq and Enter
6. Close Terminal and reopen Again. Then try executing `flutter` command

Comment: First recommendation "Provide Full Disk Access to Terminal by Setting -> Security & Privacy -> Full Disk Access. Add Terminal" works for me. Tnx.

Comment: Worked for me as well ! Thanks for help

Comment: Why we are giving full disk access to terminal ? @iamnagaky

Comment: As because we are using terminal to execute the flutter commands. I am not very sure of the specifics.

Comment: Providing full disk access worked for me. I did all the stuff given in the above answer.

Comment: Thanks.After long research I got the solution

Comment: Workin on macOs Catalina 10.15.7 (19H1519)

Comment: This worked for me! After following these steps, I deleted the flutter SDK 'cache' folder inside the bin folder, then went into my flutter project and ran flutter clean then flutter run. I'm using a macOS Big Sur, version 11.6.4, Thanks so much!

Comment: Also worked on Monterey. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using macOS Monterey Version 12.5.1, and it worked for me :)

Answer (score 65):

For me removing double quotes did the fix.

Try changing

> export PATH="$PATH:[PATH TO FLUTTER]/flutter/bin"

into

> export PATH=$PATH:[PATH TO FLUTTER]/flutter/bin

adding few more steps for easiness:

Open terminal.

```
vim $HOME/.zshrc
```

Press "I" to open insert mode.

add the following line in the opened file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:[PATH TO FLUTTER]/flutter/bin (remember I don't have double quotes here)
```

Press "Esc" then type :wq in terminal to exit edit mode.

Type
`source .zshrc` to reload the terminal for changes

Comment: `source .zshrc` to reload the terminal worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: It's weird, but it works for me. Any explanation why removing quotes helps?

Comment: for Ubuntu user's please use source ~/.zshrc instead of source .zshrc

Answer (score 44):

You must update your environment $PATH variable.

1) Open the file `$HOME/.zshrc` `$HOME` is your home path

2) add the following line in the opened file:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/YOUR_FLUTTER_DIR/flutter/bin"
```

3) save the changes and restart your terminal session.

The process is also documented [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path)

Comment: For others wondering...(stupid me, but) the 'restart terminal session' did the trick for me. (do the same in Android Studio of Visual Studio Code!)

Comment: Same here. The post important part "restart your terminal session." Or you could spend extra 1 hour.

Answer (score 31):

Follow these steps:

Open finder
Enter `Cmd + Shift + G`

Type `~` in Go to the folder popup.

Now enter `Cmd + Shift + .` to show hidden files.

Open .zshrc

Add this line

```
export PATH="$PATH:/YOUR_FLUTTER_DIR/flutter/bin"
```

Replace this /YOUR_FLUTTER_DIR with the path to your flutter directory.
In my mac, the path is

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/FlutterDevelopment/flutter/bin
```

Comment: Any explanation why removing quotes helps?

Comment: @anber: Bcz it contains a variable $PATH, which would resolve to actual path localtion. if you still want to use "" then replace $PATH with actual path. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 14):

in android studio terminal, simply just type this command:

```
export PATH="/YOUR_FLUTTER_DIR/flutter/bin:$PATH"
```

change YOUR_FLUTTER_DIR to your actual directory

Comment: I hate to admit it, but it wasn't working for me and your answer made me realize I left off the leading "/" in my path... doh!

Comment: double quotes not needed in big Sur

Answer (score 13):

I updated from Mojave to Catalina and running Terminal, switched to the default/preferred zsh shell, from the bash shell.
Then was hit with

> zsh: command not found: flutter

so, followed the advice seen elsewhere to only add the following to Users/MyUserId/.zshrc

```
export PATH="$PATH:/YOUR_FLUTTER_DIR/flutter/bin"
```

`echo $PATH` showed that `/Users/MyUserId/flutter/bin` was now one of the configured PATHs.
However, I couldn't get "flutter doctor" to work but came across a post on jelliesgame.com which suggested copying

`Users/MyUserId/.bash_profile`   to   `Users/MyUserId/.zshenv`

Now, flutter doctor gives a clean bill of health

Comment: this is because some other exports have messed your zsh profile.
Who experience similar issues - check if you have messed lines like
'export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin$PATH' and change them to export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin/:$PATH - notice : symbol before PATH

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

Steps:

1. Type on the terminal:

   ```
   open .zshrc (This opens the document in text edit)
   ```
2. Add this to the end of the file:

   ```
   export PATH="/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Documents/code/tools/flutter/bin:$PATH"
   ```
3. Save and close `.zshrc`
4. Then type:

   ```
   flutter doctor
   ```

Answer (score 9):

Had the same issue and just realized that I forgot to add the close quote

So the correct way is to add to .zshrc by typing `vim ~/.zshrc`

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Flutter/flutter/bin"
```

or

```
export PATH="$PATH:/YOUR_FLUTTER_DIR/flutter/bin"
```

then run `source ~/.zshrc` or just open a new terminal window

Answer (score 6):

I tried installing flutter on my MAC according to the advice here, but it still doesn't work, after searching for it I found an article [here](https://medium.com/@alexandrosbaramilis/setting-up-flutter-on-macos-catalina-d023df8845ae).

So, I change my .zshrc file to:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/YOUR_PROVILE_NAME/YOUR_DEVELOPMENT_FOLDER/flutter/bin"
```

Change `YOUR_PROVILE_NAME` to your **name profile**, also `YOUR_DEVELOPMENT_FOLDER` to **your development folder** for flutter

and now it's working.

**Note**:
I use Catalina OS v10.15.4

Comment: This did the trick for me as well, thanks! I'm on macOS Big Sur 11.0

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when upgrading to mac Catalina 10.15.4:

After many days of research, I have achieved success. Here are the steps I did:

First, open the terminal on your mac.

Next, use the command

```
 cat .bash_profile
```

and copy the content.

Then type this command into the terminal:

```
nano $ HOME / .zshrc
```

and paste the content just copied above into. Save then type

```
source $ HOME / .zshrc
```

to refresh this file. Next type

```
echo $ PATH
```

to see if the content has been updated. If successful type

```
flutter --version
```

and you will see the result.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few answers mentioned above pretty much same. I would say worth seeing into the SHELL using **echo $SHELL** command,

If you’re using **Bash, edit $HOME/.bash_profile or $HOME/.bashrc**. If you’re using **Z shell, edit $HOME/.zshrc**. If you’re using a different shell, the file path and filename will be different on your machine.

N.B. Don't forget you need to add VIM before either command in the terminal app.

For further details, click the link [Update your path](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos), and look into the section Update your Path. I hope it would help many especially new comers to MAC OS. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

For me **.zshrc** worked instead of **.zprofile**. I believe this is because I had created **.zshrc** earlier and now when I tried creating **.zprofile**, it was looking into .zshrc file.

You can check if **.zshrc** file using *ls -a* command

Answer (score 0):

For me moving the flutter folder to document page and setting the new path solved the issue

before-> /Users/kunalkalwar/Desktop/AndroidProjects/Softwares/flutter

after-> /Users/kunalkalwar/Documents/flutter