# flutter doesn't execute from the path

Tags: flutter, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I try to install flutter for the first time on my mac.

I followed the instructions on the [flutter get-started](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos) and I downloaded the zip for apple silicon (step 1) and unzipped the content as step2 suggested.

then in step 3, i need to run this command:

```
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
```

So I run the command using where I was unzip the files: `~`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/flutter/bin"
```

Then I restart the `wrap` terminal and try to run `flutter` but I got the error:

> zsh: command not found: flutter

Why? What is missing?

[image]

[image]

I was try to solve it by doing what the accepted [answer suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400500/after-upgrade-macos-terminal-showing-zsh-command-not-found-flutter)

But still command not found.

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400500/after-upgrade-macos-terminal-showing-zsh-command-not-found-flutter) solution?

Comment: yes. but it's still not working. I update my question

Comment: try to remove double quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `export` command does not make sense, since tilde-expansion occurs only if the tilde is at the start of an unquoted word.

It should therefore be

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/flutter/bin"
```

or simpler

```
path+=~/flutter/bin
```

Since PATH is pretty sure exported anyway, you don't need an explicit `export`.